# How to use vue-apollo in a Vuepress site?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, vuepress, vue-apollo

In a Vuepress blog site, I have a component inserted in my markdown blog posts which gets info from a database to populate its data.

I have a GraphQL server to provide the data, so I am trying to use [vue-apollo](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/) to fetch it in my component.

I tried to add vue-apollo in the `enhanceApp.js` file as such:

```js
// enhanceApp.js
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo';

// HTTP connexion to the API
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  // You should use an absolute URL here
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
});

// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

// Create the apollo client
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache,
});

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
});

export default ({ Vue, options }) => {
  Vue.use(VueApollo);
  options = {
    ...options,
    apolloProvider,
  };
};
```

And in my component file:

```js
// component.vue

export default {
  apollo: {
    architects: {
      query: gql`{
          architects {
            nodes {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    },
  },
};
```

But my `$apolloData` in the Vue component is empty, and the query is never executed.

I thought it had something to do with [Browser API Access Restrictions](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#browser-api-access-restrictions), so I tried putting the query in the `mounted()` hook:

```js
// component.vue

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$apollo
      .query({
        query: gql`{
          architects {
            nodes {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      })
      .then(result => {
        ...;
      })
}
```

which returns me an error:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultClient' of undefined"

which makes me think the setup in `enhanceApp.js` might not be working properly.

I looked a bit into [ApolloSSR](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/ssr.html#vue-cli-plugin), but it doesn't seem to suit me, as my GraphQL requests are not usually route-dependent.

A workaround I found is to use either axios or ApolloClient imported directly into my component files:

```js
// component.vue

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  // You should use an absolute URL here
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
});

export default {
mounted() {
    apolloClient
      .query({
        query: gql`{
          architects {
            nodes {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      })
      .then(result => {
        ...;
      })
}
```

which I guess could work, but I was wondering if vue-apollo is really not usable in my case.

Any hints?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.__APOLLO_CLIENT__` with your apollo configuration inside a vue component in vuepress.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing the same as you and the way I could do was this:
in enhanceApp.js change the ApolloClient to

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-boost';
```

Now in your component use this:

```
export default {
   data() {
      return {
      allData:[],
    };
   },
apollo:{
  allData:{
    query: SUB_QUERY
  }
 },
methods: {
async geData (){
  const data = await this.$apollo.query(
        {query: SUB_QUERY},
        );
       }
      },
 mounted(){
   this.getData();
   apolloClient.query({
    query: SUB_QUERY
  })
 }
};
```